# How to read sqlite file using cursor and display data in a listview

Tags: android

Hi im trying to read sqlite file which is placed in assets/databases folder

i followed this link to read data from sqlite file
http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/

im getting error

> no such table : while compiling
>   SELECT _id, name, address FROM
>   stores

Is there any permission i need to write in manifest to read sqlite file data?

Please let me know how i can solve this issue. Or else please give me any reference link to follow.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you'd want to do this is to make a new `DBManager` object that creates the database in its `onCreate` method--that way when the `DatabaseHelper` is first instantiated, the table will be created for you. Then you'd instantiate one and call `getReadableDatabase()` on it to get a DB object which you can then `query`.

This tutorial may help you more, it's more succinct and up to date: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db

After that, to set up the list view in a `ListActivity`, you can call `setListAdapter` and pass in a `SimpleCursorAdapter`. Here's a tutorial on that: http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/faq/commontasks.html#binding

Answer (score 1):

Check if database already exists or not.
If you are running on emulator.

write following on terminal/shell:

adb shell
cd data/data/your package name(ex. com.android.etc)
ls
if there exists databases directory then may be database is created

cd databases
ls

it will show your database if exists;

sqlite3 "your db name"

then write

.tables

it will show the name of table if exist:

now write your query over here to check for errors for ex:

sqlite> SELECT _id, name, address FROM stores

hope it helps.....
and yes there are no as such required permissions for this.

Comment: One thing more if database is not getting created ..... try replacing "SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase" with something like SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase.........Hope it works